# Can I define a site collection on the root of a wildcard managed path

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have defined a wildcard managed path name “documents”, and then I created the following site collections under it:-

../documents/HRDept
../documents/SalesDept
etc.

But the problem i am facing is that I can not define a site on the root of the managed path, and if I try to navigate to the following address “http../documents/” no page will be displayed. 
So if there a way to define a site collection on the root of a wild card managed path ?.

Answer (score 2):

Nope :-)

In order to get the site structure you are looking for, you would need to use a single site collection. You would have an explicit managed path '/documents', where you would create your root site collection, and then would have to create subsites underneath /documents/HRDept etc.

Comment: but i do no want to have the HRDept, SalesDept , etc, as subsites, i need them to be site collections. since each dept will be a publishing site with enterprise Wiki library template. and for each of the dept Wiki site i need to associated it with a term store taxonomy. and this can not be done if each dept is a subsite. i mean you can not link a term store to a subsite, while you can link a term store to a site collection. BR