# Site collection at root of Wildcard managed path

Tags: redirect, host-header, managed-path, path

As discussed here: [Can I define a site collection on the root of a wildcard managed path](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68739/can-i-define-a-site-collection-on-the-root-of-a-wildcard-managed-path)

It is simply not possible to have a site collection at the root of a managed path. The workaround is to use an explicit path at e.g. `/myexplicitpath` and have subwebs underneath that.

When going to `http://example.org/mywildcardpath` I get a **404** - this is not very user friendly.

I can think of two solutions:

1. How do I create my own 404 page at that location? Maybe I can leverage IIS?
2. Can I use IIS redirects, so all requests to `http://example.org/mywildcardpath` get redirected to `http://example.org`, but requests to `http://example.org/mywildcardpath/site1` go trough normally?

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different approach that gives you something along the lines of what you want, is to use Host Named Site Collections (HNSC).

You could create a HNSC Site Collection called http://mysubdomain.example.org and create sites below that:

http://mysubdomain.example.org/site1

You can only create HNSC using PowerShell, not GUI:

```
New-SPSite 'http://portal.contoso.com' -HostHeaderWebApplication 'http://<servername>’ -Name 'Portal' -Description 'Customer root' -OwnerAlias 'contoso\administrator' -language 1033 -Template 'STS#0'
```

Comment: I am actually using HNSC. I created a wildcard host header at `/mywildcardpath` and created all HNSC at `/mywildcardpath/site1` and `/mywildcardpath/site2` etc. Specifically I have the URL `http://collab.example.org` with `/community` as wildcard managed path. There also is `/proposal` and `/project`. Your example leaves out the specific wildcard path I mentioned.

Comment: yep, well I left it out on purpose. What you describe is sort of a hybrid between wildcard and explicit managed paths, and not something that I think is doable without some IIS hack as you mention. What I ment to describe was to replace the wildcard managed path with the HNSC prefix: `http://community.example.org/siteA`, `http://proposal.example.org/siteA` etc.

Comment: Ah! Good idea. Not the solution, but good idea :-) I'm currently thinking about a custom HttpRequest handler or Redirection module.